# PHP redirection goes wrong

Tags: php, form-submit

I submit all forms of my website to a specific page page `form_submition.php`, after processing the form data I redirect to another page `index.php?page=some page` using header function
but in one of my forms that named `main_form` I get a wrong redirection

```
    if(isset($_POST['form1']))
    {
        // process form data
        header('Location: ../index.php?page=some page')
    }
    if(isset($_POST['form2']))
    {
        // process form data
        header('Location: ../index.php?page=some page')
    }

    $to=$_GET['to']
    if (isset($_POST['main_form']) ) {
            // process form data
    }
    header("Location: ../index.php?page={$to}&error_loc_{$error_loc}=1&err_msj=" . $err_msj, true, 302);
    exit();
```

but it redirects me to `mywebsite.com/folders/form_submitions.php?to=all_p`

instead of `mywebsite.com/index.php?page=all_p`

any ideas?

**UPDATE 1**

I checked my code a lot, it seems that the header is not redirecting the page at all. the strange thing is that the page at `mywebsite.com/index.php?page=all_p` gets loaded but the url won't change and the css+js files not loaded because the relative path becomes invalid.

**UPDATE 2**

Further Checking my code, before submitting the `main_form` to `form_submission.php` I open a new window with javascript to print some data. the following is the form:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='./forms/form_submitions.php?to=all_p' onsubmit="return checkfiles('attachfiles')">
 .
 .
 .
    <button id="main_form" name="main_form" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
</form>
```

I call the following function when `#main_form` is clicked:

```
$("#main_form").on('click', function(event) {
newWin = window.open('printingpage.php?data='+ data);
setTimeout(function () { newWin.print(); }, 500);

});
```

Here the printing function won't return unless the print preview is closed. I think this creates the problem, because when I remove the `newWin.print()` function, everything works just fine.
is there any ways to make this printing asynchronous?

Comment: Sounds like you have another redirection somewhere, but there's not enough information for us to tell you that with confidence.

Comment: Also, this may just be semantics, I think the W3C spec on the `Location` header notes that the url passed should be absolute.

Comment: dont use ../ instead write the whole url

Comment: @Brad I don't have any unknown redirection, all of my redirections are in compound statements except for the one that goes wrong.

Comment: @War10ck Apparently, that's changed recently!  It's now possible to use relative `Location` headers.

Comment: @War10ck even changing it to absolute path returns the same result.

Comment: @Brad I have updated the question. The concrete problem is the new page is loaded but the url is not changing.

Answer (score -1):

remove .. parts in your paths & try.

So the code will be :

```
 if(isset($_POST['form1']))
    {
        // process form data
        header('Location: /index.php?page=some page')
    }
    if(isset($_POST['form2']))
    {
        // process form data
        header('Location: /index.php?page=some page')
    }

    $to=$_GET['to']
    if (isset($_POST['main_form']) ) {
            // process form data
    }
    header("Location: /index.php?page={$to}&error_loc_{$error_loc}=1&err_msj=" . $err_msj, true, 302);
    exit();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Put your web link in your redirection link.

```
$data = array(
      'page' => $to,
      'error_loc_'.$error_loc => 1,
      'err_msj' => $err_msj
);

header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?".http_build_query($data), true, 302);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Use `http_build_query()` instead of just concatenating data into a URL.